# best format to save arrays (cubes) in armadillo to load later in R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I'm running a program in `armadillo` and save a `cube` object (equivalent to a 3-dimensional array in `R`) of `doubles` using the command `mycube.save("mycube", arma_ascii)`. However I have not been able to load it properly in R.

What do you think would be the best format to use in order to load it in `R`?

Comment: @mtall I understand from the `armadillo` doc that the `raw_ascii` format for a `cube`object would store the data as a matrix concatenating all individual matrices vertically, ¿am I interpreting this right?

Answer (score 2):

A while back i stored matrices from a c++ program with:

```
m.save( "myMatrix.data" ,raw_ascii)
```

and read it in an R script with:

```
m <- as.matrix(read.table("myMatrix.data"))
```

This worked quite well. However, I'm not sure about saving cubes - you may need to split it in slices and re-assemble it in R.

Answer (score 2):

We currently seem to have "half" of the needed support: only a `wrap()` method to return `Cube` objects to R.

So if someone were to contribute a working `as<>()` converter, we could (trivially) rely on R's (nice, binary, compressed, ...) serialization via e.g. the `saveRDS()` and `loadRDS()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the format `raw_ascii` can do the trick. It is not exactly an array of 3 dimensions but a matrix concatenating (row-wise) all the individual matrices which could then be manipulated.